# Updating by concatenating columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error

I need to set the hotelcode by concatenating it with the vendorcitycode (separated by an underscore) as follows.

```
update schema.table_name set
       hotelcode = hotelcode+"_"+vendorcitycode)
 where vendorid = 'INV27' and vendorcitycode = 'LON'
```

Note : 
`hotelcode` and `vendorcitycode` are two columns of type `character varying(100)`. 
I use PostgreSQL 8.0.

Comment: I don't know if this is why you got the downvote, but the answer is easily found in the documentation. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL PostgreSQL version 8.0 is out of support; you should *really* arrange to upgrade soon. http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
UPDATE   table_name
SET      hotelcode = hotelcode || '_' || vendorcitycode
WHERE    (vendorid, vendorcitycode) = ('INV27', 'LON')
```